# Sending the id value of a div through angular js ajax to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I have number of divs, with different ids. What i am trying to do it , when that specific div is clicked, a js function will be called and the id value of that div will be sent to php and assigned to a php variable, and then response will be gotten. I need it to be done through angular js ajax, $http method. This is my simple ajax method, what i have to do now ?

```js
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ppp" ng-repeat="id in d" data-id="32">


function divClick(id){

  var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form- urlencoded'};
  var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
  app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$http){
      $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"files.php",

        headers:headers
      }).then(function(res){  }
      })
  });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the data to send:

```
$http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"files.php",
        data: {
          "id": id
        },
        headers:headers
      })
```

And change your header in order to set as content: `application/json`

Comment: and how to get it in php variable then ?

Comment: you need to decode the json object and then access the id property of the obj. This should work: `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true); echo $obj["id"];`

Comment: p.s. send it as JSON directly that it is also easier to read, I updated the code in the answer too