# pasing javascript variable to php through angular js ajax

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

i have a javascript variable, to which a specific value has been assigned. I want to send that variable value php variable through angular js ajax. My Code is follwing, please check it and tell me how should i collect the javascript variable value in php and then I can echo it. i am around done with the angular js ajax work, but i don't know how to collect that value in php now . THanks

```js
       function sendVal(event){
        var x = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');

          var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
           var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
           app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$http){
               
               $http({
                method:"POST",
                url:"files.php?data_val=true",
                data:{
                      data_val : x
                },
                headers:headers
               }).then(function(res){ })

           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your POST request should be in this way (you were appending also the value in the URL as GET, I removed it because I suppose it is a mistake but I don't know if you have some weird logic in PHP which looks for that variable in GET too):

```
var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
$http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"files.php",
        data: {
          "data_val": x
        },
        headers:headers
      })
```

And then in PHP you should have something like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$obj = json_decode($json, true); 
echo $obj["data_val"];
```

Comment: I don't know why its not working for me, do you know any source tutorial which can help me out ?

Comment: this is an answer of two hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230088/sending-the-id-value-of-a-div-through-angular-js-ajax-to-php-variable/44230127?noredirect=1#comment75470208_44230127